# Finding a frame for a vector bundle in a smooth manifold with a connection

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $P$ be a vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$ with a connection $\nabla$, and let $p \in M$ . Show that there is an open set $U$ of $M$ with $p \in U$ and a frame $E_1, \ldots, E_k$ of $P$ defined in $U$ such that for all $v \in T_pM, \nabla_v \ E_i = 0$, for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$.

However, I am not sure how to begin, and I would like some sort of hint, if possible - how would one define such a frame? Is there some intuitive way of doing it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please improve your title so that it describes exactly what your question is.  This will help future users find your question and will also help your question receive more answers.

Comment: I don't understand how the riemannian structure intervenes in the question. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You're right, it actually doesn't. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work over a coordinate patch $U$ around $p$ with local coordinates $\phi:U\xrightarrow{\sim\,}\Bbb R^n$ ($n$ is the dimension of $M$). Take a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_r)$ a basis of the ($r$-dimensional) vector space $P_p$. Extend it to a local basis of $P|_U$ by the formula
$$\forall q\in U,\,E_i(q)=\mathrm{PT}^\nabla_{\gamma_{q}}(e_i)$$
Where $\mathrm{PT}^\nabla_\gamma$ is parallel transport (in the sense of $\nabla$) along a path $\gamma$, and $\gamma_{q}:[0,1]\to M$ is the path connecting $p$ to $q$ defined by
$$\phi(\gamma_{q}(t))=\phi(p)+t(\phi(q)-\phi(p))$$
$(E_1,\dots,E_r)$ form a basis of sections of $P$ over $U$, and you can check (almost by definition) that $\left(\nabla E_j\right)_p=0$.

Comment: Can you point out a reference in which I can find a proof of existence of parallel transport in an arbitrary vector bundle? (So far I've seen it only for the tangent bundle.) And thank you for your answer.

Comment: @sylvia You'll find it in these notes: http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~vincent.minerbe/m2dg.pdf (page 41 and onwards). The gist is that parallel transport along a fixed curve obeys a first order linear differential equation, and thus exists and is smooth in the parameters (i.e. the curve and the starting vector).